# Parametric Equation of a Hyperbolic Paraboloid

Tags: calculus, parametric, hyperbolic-functions

I need to make two trace plots of the hyperbolic paraboloid $z=x^2-y^2$.

In the first plot, we set $z$ equal to a constant $k$, $z=k$. How do I find the parametric equation for this representation of $k = x^2-y^2$?

In the second plot, we set $x$ equal to a constant $k$, so  $x=k$. How do I find the parametric equation for the equation $k = \sqrt{z+y^2}$?

Comment: The matter is _parametric equations of conics_.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you divide whole the equation by $k$ to get:
$$
1=\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{k}}\right)^2-\left(\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{k}}\right)^2
$$
Now you do a substitution with trigonometric functions. It's a common trick when you are dealing with second powers.
$$
x=\sqrt{k}\sec \phi \\
$$
where $\phi$ is our parameter. And you get:
$$
1=\sec^2\phi-\left(\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{k}}\right)^2=\frac{1}{\cos^2\phi}-\left(\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{k}}\right)^2\\
\left(\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{k}}\right)^2=\frac{1}{\cos^2\phi}-1=\frac{1-\cos^2\phi}{\cos^2\phi}=\frac{\sin^2\phi}{\cos^2\phi}=\tan^2\phi
$$
therefore:
$$
y=\sqrt{k}\tan \phi
$$

The second one is easy. You have $z=k^2-y^2$. If you say $y=t$ where $t$ is our parameter, you get $z=k^2-t^2$.